# simple Node js program but the order of execution seems different?

Tags: node.js

The below node JS program order of execution is totally different, can anyone explain to me how the execution is happening?

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  
  function getname()
  {
        let name=""
        readline.question('Who are you?', name => 
        {
            console.log(`Hey there ${name}!`);
            readline.close();
        });
        return name
}`enter code here`
console.log('My name is'+ getname())
```

output :
Who are you?My name is
Summer
Hey there Summer!

I only got to understand that this code doesn't work in sequence order as Node JS is asynchronous programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has 2 parts

- How`readline.question` library works
- Evaluation of a statement

```
The rl.question() method displays the query by writing it to the output, waits for user input to be provided on input, then invokes the callback function passing the provided input as the first argument.
```

So in the above example, for Node to print out value of `'My name is'+ getname()`, it has to evaluate this expression.

The evaluation returns nothing as name is empty. But as `readline.question` gets executed, it prints out `Who are you ?` as the `question` method `displays the query by writing it to output`

As the evaluation of `'My name is'+ getname()` is complete, it prints `My name is` and waits for the prompt to input. Lets say thats `gp`

Once thats done, it would print the input `gp` (*obviously as we typed it*) followed by the callback output i.e `Hey there gp!`

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Yeah, I can understand the flow now, but how can I get the name which I passed via user input instead of getting it as empty? is there any way to find out?

Comment: Checkout [readline-sync]('https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync')

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations:

1. You are executing the function inside the console.log first (`getname()`)
2. `getname()` is causing the stdin prompt to display "Who are you?"
3. It is executing *synchonously* so it displays the question
4. Synchronously, the input is received from the stdin (you type it at the prompt) which then evaluates the `console.log('My name is' + getname())` expression.
5. the `getname()` logic now finished, then outputs 'Hey there Summer!' on the console.

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline) may help here as well:

```js
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

const answer = await rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ');

console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

rl.close();
```